# mime type and versioning in spring

Tags: java, spring, mime-types, hal

I am trying to add a version to my api with the following :

```
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/public/api/item", produces = "application/vnd.company.api.v1+hal+json")
```

and am getting an exception : 
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

The problem seems to be that the mime type does not support more than 1 + sign and type.  If i limit the type to only vnd.company.api.v1+json then it works.

Anyone know if mime types are limited to only 2 + characters and if someone has used versioning with hal+json type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `hal+json` an extension itself? In other words, I don't think your suffix should be `+hal+json`, it's just `+json` with your unique vendor prefix (which can include `hal` somewhere).

What about using a `.` instead of `+` as some other organizations have done?

```
application/vnd.company.api.v1.hal+json
```

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: Correct, thats waht i have fond from various examples as well.  Just include the hal portion as part of the vnd definition seperated wither by a . or a - . Thanks.